# Setting Up Multiple Grunt files

Tags: gruntjs

I want to run grunt on several projects simultaneously. However i'm not sure how to setup so it works. Here's what my setup looks like:

```
- Project 1 folder
   -[project files]
   -Gruntfile

- Project 2 folder
   -[project files]
   -Gruntfile

- Grunt Folder 
  -[nodeModules]
  -package.json
```

So the idea is that have all grunt dependencies (node modules) in a single centralised folder. Then each project folder has its own Gruntfile.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to setup the gruntFile so that it can use the node modules and package.json from the grunt dependancy folder.

Can anyone help me with how I can get this to work? Specifically with code examples.

Comment: may be related to: [Can I have multiple gruntjs files in my project for code organization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694385/can-i-have-multiple-gruntjs-files-in-my-project-for-code-organization)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. That plugin runs a single grunt task which directs to multiple gruntfiles - I want to run them individually.