# Multiple gruntfile.js in one project folder?

Tags: gruntjs

```
I have a main project with a grunt compile process:
root/main/stuff/...
root/gruntfile.js
root/package.json
```

Now within the same project root folder I'd like to create an additional module that should be compilable independent of the main project:

Pseudo-code:

```
root/services/moduleA
root/gruntfile-moduleA.js
root/package-moduleA.json
```

Question: is that possible at all? How can I have multiple gruntfiles with different names in the same project layout?

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your needs:

https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub

This also might be a dupe of:

[Can I have multiple gruntjs files in my project for code organization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694385/can-i-have-multiple-gruntjs-files-in-my-project-for-code-organization)