# How can a registered Gruntfile task run the subtask concat if it has not been configured there?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

The legacy Gruntfile I'm working with has multiple build tasks that include the subtask `'concat'`, but it is never configured in the context of the Gruntfile (read: a search for concat turns up nothing relevant). The build task does work though and I can see this in my terminal:

```
Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File .tmp/concat/app/vendor.css created.
File .tmp/concat/app/app.css created.
File .tmp/concat/app/vendor.js created.
File .tmp/concat/app/app.js created.
```

I need to add configurations to the task but at the moment I can't begin to even find it. Is there another way this task can be configured? Is there such thing as a `concat` default?- I didn't see anything remotely implying that in the docs. Any intuitions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps using [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks)?

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle with the entire grunt file

Comment: Sure thing. It is huge, just a heads up. I've removed some information, but here it is in all it's terrifying glory: https://jsfiddle.net/nq4800nb/

Comment: The build tasks are registered at the very bottom of the file

Comment: @steveax, we use load-grunt-tasks, but for other modules

Comment: @BigHeadCreations, forgot to tag you, jsFiddle is above

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find a solution for you without having access to the entire project, but here are a few ideas:

Are there multiple Grunt files? [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302620/2959670) I am asking this because I see where the concat task is called in the buildProd and buildDev tasks but I don't ever see the task even get loaded (via `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat')`). So if you see the concat task running in your console output it must be defined somewhere else.

You state the console output says `Running "concat:generated"`. Trying doing a project wide search for `concat` and `generated`, maybe something will pop up.

Lastly, try just adding the concat task there in your gruntfile and see what happens. Load the task, configure it with the configurations you need and see if it works or if you get any errors that could possibly lead you in the right direction.